# Fine Grained Notifications old/new RLMResults

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am trying to find out the inserted/deleted objects after a write transaction.

With the fine grained notification block I can get:

```
/// The indices of objects in the previous version of the collection which have
/// been removed from this one.
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray<NSNumber *> *deletions;

/// The indices in the new version of the collection which were newly inserted.
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray<NSNumber *> *insertions;
```

My question is in this snippet:

```
RLMResults *contacts = [CYRLMAddressBookContact allObjects];
RLMNotificationToken *token = [contacts addNotificationBlock:^(RLMResults *_Nullable results,
                            RLMCollectionChange *_Nullable change,
                            NSError *_Nullable error) {}];
```

Could `contacts` be considered a "previous version" of the collection?

If not is it safe to convert `contacts` to an `NSArray` and that would be a "previous version" of the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code sample, when the notification block fires, `contacts` will already be in the updated state. The `deletions` and `insertions` values will be in relation to the updated state so that any UI elements still displaying the previous state of each item in `contacts` may be updated to match.

No, I don't think it's unsafe to do that. If you copied the contents of `contacts` to an `NSArray`, that would certainly capture the previous ordering of `contacts` before the notification. Realm objects are live though, so if the property values inside any of the `contacts` objects changed, that would be reflected in the array as well.

That being said, you do need to be careful when copying objects from `RLMResults` to an `NSArray`. Directly touching each object as you pass it to the array will cause it to be lazy-loaded by Realm, which may result in a performance hit.

Comment: Thank you @TiM. That was helpful. What I want to do here is not UI related. But I do need to know the inserted and deleted objects after the update. Do you know of a better way to accomplish this without copying the objects to an NSArray? In these cases Realm could pass the two copies of the result set, the previous and new versions.

Comment: No problems! Glad I could help! Oh really? At the moment, we've been focussing the fine-grained notifications feature on primarily UI-based changes. What sort of use case are you working on then? We'd be interested to hear about that! Not at the moment sorry. Your best bet at the moment would be the NSArray approach. There was discussion about providing the 'old' objects in the notification block as well, but at present, it would be difficult and time-consuming to add.

Comment: I've only seen this reply today. Sorry. I've been following Realm for some time now. I understand your priorities. I was trying to leverage fine grained notifications in a synchronisation solution. Where I would sync AddressBook contacts to a table in realm, and afterwards I would need to know which contacts were added/deleted/updated so that I could communicate that to our remote server.